How do Lutherans interpret the church is the pillar of truth in 1 Timothy 3:15?
Recently I had a conversation with a Roman Catholic about apostolic succession and the papacy and he brought up this verse:
1 Timothy 3:15 KJV

But if I tarry long, that thou mayest know how thou oughtest to behave thyself in the house of God, which is the church of the living God, the pillar and ground of the truth.

My first understanding of this is that the pillar of truth being the church is the community of believers that come together in a spiritual sense rather than an earthly church institution. That is sound to me from what I've read from both the book of Concord and Luther's writings along with scriptural basis. Would this be the general consensus of the Lutheran doctrine for what the church is?, or am I missing something?

Short version: "yes". As a protestant, I came to the same conclusion as you before reading your last paragraph. I don't know about specific Lutheran writings supporting that, though.

@Matthew the Art. VII & VIII: Of the Church of the apology of the Augsburg confession clarifies the Augsburg confessions Article VII. Of the Church and Article VIII. What the Church Is. And it says Church Catholic, in order that we may not understand the Church to be an outward government of certain nations [that the Church is like any other external polity, bound to this or that land, kingdom, or nation, as the Pope of Rome will say], but rather men scattered throughout the whole world - Art. VII & VIII: Of the Church:10
